# What's the equivalent of new and delete using allocators?

Tags: c++, allocator

C++ allocators (as used by `std::vector`) are tricky to. I understand that they changed a lot to allow stateful allocators and PMR, leading to some of the cruftiness. My core question is: if allocators are intended to replace `new` and `delete`, why do they only provide an API like `malloc` and `free`? I understand why, e.g., `std::vector` needs a `malloc` interface since it needs to allocate a buffer without calling constructors, but in general, it seems like we are missing these functions:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

//! Rebind alloc to type T
template <typename T, typename Alloc> 
auto rebound_allocator(const Alloc& alloc) {
    return typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<T>{alloc};
}

//! Like operator delete but for a single T allocated by rebound_allocator<T>(alloc).
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
void allocator_delete(const Alloc& alloc, T* ptr) {
    assert(ptr);
    auto a = rebound_allocator<T>(alloc);
    using traits_t = std::allocator_traits<decltype(a)>;
    // Should we try/catch around destroy and always deallocate?
    traits_t::destroy(a, ptr);
    traits_t::deallocate(a, ptr, 1);
}

//! Returned memory must be freed with, e.g., allocator_delete(alloc, ptr).
template <typename T, typename Alloc, typename... Args>
[[nodiscard]] T* allocator_new(const Alloc& alloc, Args&&... args) {
    auto a = rebound_allocator<T>(alloc);
    using traits_t = std::allocator_traits<decltype(a)>;
    auto deallocate = [&a](T* ptr) { traits_t::deallocate(a, ptr, 1); };
    // Hold in a unique_ptr to deallocate if construction throws.
    auto buf = std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(deallocate)>(traits_t::allocate(a, 1), deallocate);
    traits_t::construct(a, buf.get(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return buf.release();
}

//! Like make_unique. Beware: The allocator is is referenced by the deleter!
template <typename T, typename Alloc, typename... Args>
[[nodiscard]] auto allocator_make_unique(const Alloc& alloc, Args&&... args) {
    auto dtor = [&alloc](T* ptr) { allocator_delete<T>(alloc, ptr); };
    return std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(dtor)>(allocator_new<T>(alloc, std::forward<Args>(args)...),
                                              dtor);
}

struct S {
    float x;
    S(float x) : x(x) { std::cout << "S::S()" << std::endl; }
    ~S() { std::cout << "S::~S()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::allocator<int> alloc;

    auto ptr = allocator_make_unique<S>(alloc, 42.5f);
    assert(ptr);
    std::cout << ptr->x << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
S::S()
42.5
S::~S()
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sheec6br3

Am I missing something? Is this the right way to implement essentially `new` and `delete` and `make_unique` using allocators? If so, is this really not provided by the standard library?

Edit:
I think (but am not sure?) that if `T` is allocator-aware, `traits_t::construct(a, ptr, n)` will propagate itself into the created object?

Edit:
Here's a cleaned-up version: https://godbolt.org/z/47Tdzf4W7

Edit:
Original version: https://godbolt.org/z/dGW7hzdc1

Comment: I almost didn't include that part for simplicity. I just creation functions returning raw pointers. Although the lambda has a reference that could dangle, so I'm not sure if it adds much. The focus of my question is trying to be about correctly implementing the equivalent of `new`. Once you have that, the equivalent of `make_unique` isn't too hard.

Comment: So, basically, are you asking about a (possibly library) function that "merges" allocator-aware storage allocation with object initialization? Similarly, as new expression "merges" operator new with placement new?

Comment: @DanielLangr that's right. I want to combine rebinding, allocation, and construction in `allocator_new` and `allocator_delete` (which is what I named them in https://godbolt.org/z/47Tdzf4W7). I want it both because there are places I want to use them, and because a reference implementation clarifies the exception-correct usage of allocators in the case where allocation and construction are separated.

Comment: I would then suggest changing the title of the question since, as for now, it is too generic and does not reflect this particular problem.

Comment: It does appear that `traits_t::construct` passes the allocator in to allocator-aware `T`s: https://godbolt.org/z/W3zPT7Es8

Comment: Also, it appears that `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>` does provide roughly what I want in `new_object` and `delete_object`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/new_object https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/delete_object

Answer (score 2):

> My core question is: if allocators are intended to replace new and delete, why do they only provide an API like malloc and free?

The API of allocators are such as it is because an important point of allocators is that memory allocation and object creation must be separated. This is necessary for example to implement a container such as `std::vector`. Allocators are a generalisation of operator new / delete, not generalisation of the new expression.

> is this really not provided by the standard library?

No, these functions aren't provided by the standard library.

> Is this the right way to implement essentially new and delete and make_unique using allocators?
>
> ```
> auto dtor = [&alloc](T* ptr) { destruct_and_deallocate(alloc, ptr); };
>              ^
> ```

Capturing allocator by reference into the deleter seems bad. It should be copied to be safe.

Other suggestions:

- In the default case of `std::allocator`, we would like to avoid paying for the overhead of the deleter. Consider adding a specialisation that delegates to `std::make_unique` when `std::allocator` is used.
- You could avoid the try-catch by using an intermediary unique pointer with deleter that only deallocates:

  ```
  T* ptr = traits_t::allocate(rebound_alloc, 1);
  auto dealloc = [&](T* ptr) { traits_t::deallocate(rebound_alloc, ptr, 1); };
  std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(dealloc)> storage(ptr, dealloc);
  traits_t::construct(rebound_alloc, storage.get(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  auto dtor = [alloc](T* ptr) { destruct_and_deallocate(alloc, ptr); };
  return std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(dtor)>(storage.release(), dtor);
  ```

---

> Edit: I think (but am not sure?) that if T is allocator-aware, traits_t::construct(a, ptr, n) will propagate itself into the created object?

No, object's have no knowledge of the allocator that creates them or allocates their memory. "Allocator aware" containers are simply generic tempaltes that allow the user to provide a custom allocator, and avoid allocating memory through other means.

Comment: I understand that part, but doing the equivalent of `new` and `delete` exception-correctly is very tricky. (As eval as throwing d'tors are, I'm not sure if I should catch, deallocate, and rethrow in the `delete` equivalent!) While `vector` needs raw memory, node-based structures may not. The fact that the functions are so long tells me they are algorithms that deserve a name. (And possibly even should be factored into smaller functions, like `template <typename T, typename Alloc> auto rebind(Alloc& alloc) { return typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<T>{alloc}; }`.)

Comment: @Ben You should mark your deletor `noexcept`, so that if an exception is thrown, `std::terminate` is called.

Comment: @vll thanks, that's right: it doesn't matter if the d'tor throws, "leaking" the underlying memory because it will `std::terminate` either way.